# How to fetch data from an HTTP with blocked loading mixed active content in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to load some data from an http website using a fetch request, which works great when my app is running on the local host.

The problem is the site I'm fetching from doesn't support https, so when I try running it on github pages my browser blocks the request.

I understand this is for security purposes, so it is impossible to fetch data from an http if I'm on an https like github pages? Or is there some way to get this to go through?

Comment: is it a CORS problem ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: It looks like the issue is just that the browser won't let me fetch data from an http if I'm on an https. If I choose 'disable protection for now' on my browser it works fine.